# What function/macro to check what namespaces are currently 'used' and how to check if one in particular is used?

Tags: namespaces, clojure

Is there a function/macro in Clojure to check what namespaces are currently **'used'**? Which one? So I don't mean 'what namespace are we currently in' but for example, I want to find out if 'clojure.contrib.string' is currently 'used' as in `(use 'clojure.contrib.string)`. I don't mean 'required'.

How does one write a function that give true when for example 'clojure.contrib.string (the name of the namespace provided via a symbol) is used and false otherwise?
(defn ns-used? [name] (...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[all-ns](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/all-ns) as suggested by kotarak, is close to what you are looking for, but it also gives you all the namespaces that have been `required` without having been referred.

Otherwise [ns-refers](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/ns-refers) gives you a map of all the functions that are referred in the namespace. Similar and possibly also of interest are  [ns-map](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/ns-map) and [ns-imports](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/ns-imports) which gives you a mapping of all the imported classes or records.

If you want to strictly find all the namespaces from which functions have been referred, you could do something like this:

```
(defn ns-used? [ns]
  (let [referred-namespaces (set (map (fn [[k v]] (:ns (meta v))) (ns-refers *ns*)))] 
    (contains? referred-namespaces (find-ns ns))))
```

If you are happy to check if the namespace has been `required` or `used` you could do

```
(defn ns-used-or-required? [ns]
  (contains? (set (all-ns)) (find-ns ns)))
```

You will have to pass the symbol in quoted:

```
(ns-used? 'clojure.core)
```

Comment: @MichielBorkent I did some digging and `all-ns` actually gives you also all the `required` namespaces. See my answer for a solution to get all namespace from which functions have been referred (as the case when you `use` a namespace).

Comment: Well, yes, see my edited post. The `(set (map ...))` stuff gets all the namespaces from where functions have been referred.

Answer (score 0):

[all-ns](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/all-ns) for some suitable definition of 'used'.

[ns-refers](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/ns-refers) for some other definition of 'used'.